# Shiny Layout - Header panel with navlist / navbarpage

Tags: r, shiny

I need to the following Shiny Layout:

1. Header Panel - With a date range filter. This will be common to all panels (below)
2. Below the Header Bar, a navigation bar with 3 distinct tab panels (lets call them Tab Panel1, Tab Panel 2, Tab PaAnel 3). Each of these Tab PAnels will have their own filters and display some charts.

I have tried navbarPage, navlistPAnel without success.

navbarPage attempt: I dont see the date filter

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Wiser",
                   header = headerPanel("Choose Dates", dateRangeInput("id1", "Date Range:",
                                                              min = "2015-03-01",
                                                              max   = Sys.Date(),
                                                              start = "2015-07-01", 
                                                              end = "2015-07-31")),
                   tabPanel("Component 1"),
                   tabPanel("Component 2"),
                   navbarMenu("More",
                              tabPanel("Sub-Component A"),
                              tabPanel("Sub-Component B"))
))
```

navlistPanel attempt: Again I dont see the date filter in the header

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Application Title"),
  headerPanel("Choose Dates", dateRangeInput("id1", "Date Range:",
                             min = "2015-03-01",
                             max   = Sys.Date(),
                             start = "2015-07-01", 
                             end = "2015-07-31")),
  navlistPanel(
   tabPanel("Component 1"),
    tabPanel("Component 2"),
   tabPanel("Component 3")
   )
))
```

Comment: Have you tried using `header = fluidRow( ...)` inside the `navbarPage`?